# Name for the surface generated by 3D in 4D space and has it has been studied somewhere!!

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, surfaces

I recently come across the equation of the form:

$$ 0 = - 5 + 4(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2) + 16 x y z w$$

As can be seen, it is quartic in four variables $x,y,z,w$. This yields a three-dimensional surface in a four-dimensional space. To visualize four-dimensional space, just like in four-dimensional spacetime, we can consider $w$ a "time variable" and study the three-dimensional surfaces $(x,y,z)$ for fixed $w$.

However, my question is, whether the above surface has a name and whether it has been studied somewhere (i.e. solution of the above polynomial equations)?
For e.g., when $w =1,-1$, I suspect that it is related to the "Cayley nodal cubic surface".

Comment: Thinking of $w$ as a time variable would probably make more sense if you had $-w^2$ instead of $w^2$, so the equation describing your hypersurface would at least have a "Minkowski" term. I would try computing the curvature of that and see if you get more properties which would help you refine the search...

Comment: @IvoTerek I agree with you. It's completely not equivalent to time (maybe imaginary time). But it was just to visualize it in 3D, nothing more for a fixed value of $w$. However, it is a good idea to go to the curvature. But I'm mostly interested in the solution to the equation.

Comment: Right. Rescaling all the coordinates by a factor of $2$, your equation is equivalent to $x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2+xyzw = 5$. This seems nicer to work with. Maybe it is a minimal hypersurface? Or CMC?

Comment: Also, if just to get intuition, I'd look at the surface $x^2+y^2+z^3 + xyz = c$ in $\Bbb R^3$ first.

Comment: Just a quick comment: your equation is not quadratic; it's quartic.

Comment: @IvoTerek I agree with the rescaling. I also noticed it. Thanks, looks like a good start to get some intuition. I couldn't get when you said is it minimal hypersurface? Fully motivated by you, now I think even simple $x^2 + y^2 + xy = c$, too lazy ;)

Comment: @JackLee You're right, my mistake.